# Where do i get drivers for a BCM 43143 dongle

Tags: driver, firmware

I have a WiFi dongle which has a BCM 43143 chipset
I'm running Raspbian Wheezy on my raspberry pi and I've tried everything I found on the internet to fix it the WiFi connection problem
I can find the dongle on lsusb but there doesn't seem to be the driver for it in dmesg.
I'm not an advanced Linux user and I mostly use Windows.
Can anyone tell me where I can find the drivers and how I install them on my raspberry pi?
When I run `ifconfig`, I get an output for eth0 and lo but not wlan0.

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:bd1e Broadcom Corp.
```

`lsusb -t` output:

```
1-1.3:1.0: No such file or directory
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=, 480M
```

When I run the commands above that is what I get, I'm guessing my device is the one with id 0a5c:bd1e?

sudo ifconfig -a gives:

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:b4:1d:3a
          inet addr:192.168.0.11  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:254 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:198 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:19688 (19.2 KiB)  TX bytes:27779 (27.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
But no wlan0

Also sudo ifdown wlan0 gives nothing but

sudo ifup wlan0 gives:
-> wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
-> run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
->Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory
-> wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_cli daemon failed to start
-> run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1

What is this supposed to mean?

And if this is any more help - when I run sudo ifup wlan0:
-> ifup: interface wlan0 already configured

My goal is not functionality but learning.. so how do I install the firmware
Many thanks for your help !! :)

Comment: I use desktop linux systems, and for similar chipsets to that I have to use the `wl` proprietary Broadcom driver :/ I'm not sure's whether is available for the Pi (or for ARM architectures generally) though. Could you please add the output for `lsusb` and `lsusb -t` to your question? (this can be [edit]ed in) Also the newer Raspbian Jessie images may work better.

Comment: It would appear this is supportable https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=102458&p=709423 however if you are new to dealing with Linux and your goal is functionality rather than learning you might consider just buying an inexpensive dongle known to be more widely supported by existing pi images.

Comment: I have tried the link now... How do I download the firmware on the second link. it says copy into your firmware directory - which one is that? is that all i need to do?

Comment: It still doesn't recognise the dongle

Comment: After following every instruction & then rebooting my pi

Comment: after typing in sudo ifup wlan0 it outputs

Comment: wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_cli daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
and then if I try again it outputs wlan0 client alrady configured, so I have to do ifdown then ifup after that.

Comment: Fixed after installing raspbian jessie! YAY!

Answer (score 1):

I found that the best way to get this to work was to install raspbian jessie(or latest raspbian distro) on the Pi. Quite simple solution